# ¿A qué se refiere con por cada instrumento un condicional?

Tags: c++, condiciones, else

quisiera pedir ayuda con el siguiente código que estoy haciendo, la idea es un programa que categorice a partir de condicionales, los diferentes tipos de instrumentos musicales. Y al momento de ingresar un instrumento debe mostrar a qué tipo de instrumento musical pertenece, si es de
cuerda, aire, etc . Este fue un trabajo que realicé para mi clase, pero la profesora me dijo lo siguiente "debía desarrollarse,  por cada instrumento un condicional", aquí está la versión resumida del ejercicio que entregué (disminuí los instrumentos para que el código no se vea tan largo aquí):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string instrumento;
    
    cout << "**********Tipos de instrumentos musicales**********"<< endl;
    cout << endl <<"Ingrese uno de los siguientes instrumentos para saber a que tipo corresponden (incluir tildes):"<< endl;
    cout << endl << "Flauta";
    cout << endl << "Trompeta";
    cout << endl << "Guitarra";
    cout << endl << "Violín";
    cout << endl << "Tambor";
    cout << endl << "Batería" << endl;
    cout << endl << "Seleacción: ";
    cin >> instrumento;
    
    if (instrumento == "Flauta" || instrumento == "Trompeta")
    {
        cout << endl << "Usted ingreso " << instrumento << " el cual pertenece a los instrumentos de viento";
    }
    else if (instrumento == "Guitarra" || instrumento == "Violín")
    {
        cout << endl << "Usted ingreso " << instrumento << " el cual pertenece a los instrumentos de cuerda";
    }
    else if (instrumento == "Tambor" || instrumento == "Batería")
    {
        cout << endl << "Usted ingreso " << instrumento << " el cual pertenece a los instrumentos de percusión";
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << endl <<instrumento << " no estaba dentro de las opciones";
    }
    

    return 0;
}
```

Entonces, mi profesora me pidió que corrigiera el ejercicio, pero no entendía exactamente a que se refería si yo había puesto un condicional para cada tipo de instrumento, yo le pregunté lo mismo, a lo que ella me respondió:

Ejemplo

```
cin>>instrumentos;
if(instrumentos== flauta || instrumentos== sacsofon)
cout<<"usted escribe los instrumentos de viento ";
else
cout<<"otro instrumento de ..."
```

Pero seguía sin entender y mi profesora ya no me responde, tomando en cuente el ejemplo pensé que tal vez era deja de usar else if y usar solo if y else, pero la verdad el resultado no me parece que sea muy práctico y tampoco encuentro la manera de que solo se imprima por pantalla a que instrumento pertenece y omitir al que no pertenece, este es el ejercicio que tengo hecho, aunque si cumple su función la verdad tengo dudas si sea un buen ejercicio o si haya cumplido la corrección de mi profesora:

```
#include <iostream>

int
main ()
{
  std::string instrumento;
  std::
    cout << "****************Tipos de instrumentos musicales****************"
    << std::endl << std::endl;
  std::
    cout << "Escriba alguno de los siguientes instrumentos para saber a que"
    << std::
    endl << "tipo pertenece (no incluir espacios, incluir ortografía):" <<
    std::endl << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Saxofón" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Flauta" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Clarinete" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Trompeta" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Guitarra" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Arpa" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Violín" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Piano" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Timbal" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Tambor" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Platillos" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Bombo" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "BajoEléctrico" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "GuitarraEléctrica" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Theremín" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Sintetizador" << std::endl << std::endl;
  std::cout << "\nInstrumento:";
  std::cin >> instrumento;

  if (instrumento == "Saxofón" || instrumento == "Flauta"
      || instrumento == "Clarinete" || instrumento == "Trompeta")
    {
      std::cout << std::
    endl << "El " << instrumento <<
    " pertenece al tipo de instrumento de viento" << std::endl;
      
    }
  else
    {
      std::cout << std::
    endl << "El instrumento " << instrumento <<
    " no pertenece al tipo de instrumento de viento" << std::endl;
      
    }
  if (instrumento == "Guitarra" || instrumento == "Arpa"
      || instrumento == "Violín" || instrumento == "Piano")
    {
      std::cout << std::
    endl << "El " << instrumento <<
    " pertenece al tipo de instrumento de cuerda" << std::endl;
      
    }

  else
    {
      std::cout << std::
    endl << "El instrumento " << instrumento <<
    " no pertenece al tipo de instrumento de cuerda" << std::endl;
    
    }

  if (instrumento == "Timbal" || instrumento == "Tambor"
      || instrumento == "Platillos" || instrumento == "Bombo")
    {
      std::cout << std::
    endl << "El " << instrumento <<
    " pertenece al tipo de instrumento de percusión" << std::endl;
    }

  else
    {
      std::cout << std::
    endl << "El instrumento " << instrumento <<
    " no pertenece al tipo de instrumento de percusiC3n" << std::endl;

    }

  if (instrumento == "GuitarraEléctrica" || instrumento == "TheremC-n"
      || instrumento == "Sintetizador" || instrumento == "BajoEléctrico")
    {
      std::cout << std::
    endl << "El " << instrumento <<
    " pertenece al tipo de instrumento eléctrico" << std::endl;
    }

  else
    {
      std::cout << std::
    endl << "El instrumento " << instrumento <<
    " no pertenece al tipo de instrumento de eléctrico" << std::endl;
    return 0;
    }

  if (instrumento != "GuitarraElC)ctrica" && instrumento != "Theremín"
      && instrumento != "Sintetizador" && instrumento != "BajoEléctrico"
      && instrumento != "Guitarra" && instrumento != "Arpa"
      && instrumento != "Violín" && instrumento != "Piano"
      && instrumento != "Saxofón" && instrumento != "Flauta"
      && instrumento != "Clarinete" && instrumento != "Trompeta"
      && instrumento != "Timbal" && instrumento != "Tambor"
      && instrumento != "Platillos" && instrumento != "Bombo")
    {
      std::cout << std::
    endl <<
    "Ha ingresado un instrumento que no está en las opciones, vuelva a intentar para tener resultados correctos"
    << std::endl;
    }

  return 0;
}
```

No sé si alguien que entienda bien a lo que se refiere mi profesora me pueda ayudar a decirme si la corrección está bien o me pueda ayudar a saber como corregir adecuadamente. Sé que la idea acá no es preguntar por tareas ni pedirle a nadie que haga mi tarea, pero enserio quisiera saber si alguien me puede ayudar a entender qué es lo que tengo que hacer, he estado mucho tiempo intentado entender e investigando pero la verdad no entiendo. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Tu ejercicio está muy bien y se entiende muy bien lo que hace, hay veces en que uno no debe hacerle caso a lo que dicen los profesores, creo que este es un ejemplo

Comment: Pienso lo mismo, pero temo que la profesora no piense lo mismo y me perjudique  mi calificación :( igualmente lo importante es que entiendo, muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de leer mi pregunta y darme tu respuesta!!

Comment: Tu profesora está perdida, ella pretende que pongas un if para cada instrumento, tu haces if agrupados por un or  de modo que si pones flauta o trompeta lo calificas como viento  ella quiere que has un if para trompeta y otro aparte para flauta, esto aumenta las líneas de código, dile a tu profesora que se ponga a estudiar

Comment: No entiendo como es que te pide un if por instrumento, y luego en el ejemplo que te pone lo hace igual que como lo estas haciendo tu. Creo que tendrás que pedirle a tu profesora que se explique mejor.

Comment: Como una nota, para la verificacion de si el que ingreso no esta en las opciones. Seria mejor que tengas un `bool` hasta arriba que se llame valido y empieze en falso.  Si si es de un tipo lo colocas en verdadero, y al final en lugar de tener un monton de `instrumento != "X"`, solo revisas eso.

Comment: Lo que entiendo que quiere decir la profesora es que pongas una condicional por cada grupo de instrumentos para que el usuario sepa a qué grupo pertenece el instrumento escrito. Como son los instrumentos de viento, cuerda, etcétera